# Why is it that if a function is continuous, then $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$?

Tags: limits

Why is it that if a function is continuous, then $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$?

For example, let $f(x)=\cos x$

Why is it so that $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = \cos(0) = 1?$$ I know $\cos x$ is continuous, but why does that imply the following result.

Comment: What are you using as the definition of continuity of a function? This generally follows very quickly from the definition, but it's hard to explain that without knowing what definition you're using.

Comment: What is your definition of *continuous*? And of *limit*?

Comment: In a calculus course this is generally the definition, not something that needs to be derived. Which definition of continuous are you using?

Comment: I suspect the OP is using the naive "definition" that continuity means you can draw the graph without lifting the pencil (or pen) off the paper.

Answer (score 2):

Because a function, $f(x)$, is defined as continous as:

$$\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=f(c).$$

This is in Calculus I and II terms the much more accurate $\epsilon-\delta$ definition is the following:

> A function, $f(x)$ is continous if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|z-c|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I know that that is the definition of continuity of the function, but what is the logic behind it?

Comment: Logic behind it? This isn't a theorem it's a definition of continous think no more of the "pencil off the paper" garbage.